# Is there a single word to describe what one does on a treadmill?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, vocabulary

I'm a native speaker but I often have trouble communicating my ideas efficiently. On a treadmill, I may walk, run, or use the 'intervals' program, which switches back and forth between walking and running speeds. If I'm making a to-do list, how can I express my intention to use the treadmill most effectively?

**Some ideas:**

> *Exercise* on the treadmill

Sounds awkward to me, and *exercise* more often means strength training.

> *Walk and/or run* on the treadmill

Precise, but highly inefficient.

> *Use* the treadmill

Efficient, but imprecise.

Comment: **Exercise** does it. There is nothing about **exercise** that implies strength training. The word covers every demanding physical activity and most sports.                
 **physical activity that you do to make your body strong and healthy: ** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exercise

Comment: Perhaps **jog**?

Comment: Cardio? "Use the treadmill. Work on Cardio."?

Comment: Idiomatically, there isn't really any English verb that could be used "naturally" in a context like *Out of sheer boredom, the caged rat ???? the treadmill for hours every day.* You might just about get away with something like ***walked, ran, paced, worked*** or ***paddled*** as opposed to the totally generic verb ***used***, but it would probably be better to go for more radical rephrasing.